# Xcode: Swift Multiple Videos connecting through buttons

Tags: swift, xcode

I am having difficulty using different videos for different buttons. My first button works however, however when i click the second button it takes me to the AppDelegate.swift page. I have attached my code. Any suggestions?

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

class Chicken_visual_ViewController: UIViewController {

var playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
var playerView = AVPlayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}




override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}




@IBAction func button1(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    var fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:"/Users/owner/Desktop/video.mp4")
    playerView = AVPlayer(url: fileURL as URL)
    playerController.player = playerView


    self.present(self.playerController, animated: true, completion: {
        self.playerController.player?.play()
    })
}

@IBAction func button2(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    var fileURL2 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:"/Users/owner/Desktop//video_3. 
 mp4")
    playerView = AVPlayer(url: fileURL2 as URL)
    playerController.player = playerView


    self.present(self.playerController, animated: true, completion: {
        self.playerController.player?.play()
    })

}
```

}

Comment: it takes you to App Delegate because App Crashed. 
Hint: Check your second button's file url you have **//**

Comment: sorry ignore that... i deleted some of the path when posting the comment, in the original code there is only one "/"